# Choose between two queryBuilders in a method

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have an awkward situation with a method that is used on two different places, thus require two different `queryBuilders`.

On one place I need the method to use this `queryBuilder`;

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager('admin')->createQueryBuilder();
```

And somewhere else I need the `queryBuilder` to be this;

```
$queryBuilder = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('admin')->createQueryBuilder();
```

How can I accomplish this in the same method? Because the rest of it will be exactly the same if I made two different methods, and that feels unnecessary.

Something like, try this one and if not working catch and try the other one.

Comment: Where are this methods, controller, sercvice...

Comment: inject the QueryBuilder into the method or preferably into the service/class the method lives in. At some point up the stack, you should know and make the decision of which QB you need to use.

Comment: One is in a Controller extending from Symfony's Controller and the other place is inside configureListFields in an Admin that extends from Sonata's Admin

Comment: @Callistino do you mind explain or show how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just give the method the correct querybuilder via a parameter.
If you want Querybuilder1.

```
$queryBuilder1 = .......;
callOfFunction($queryBuilder1);
```

same goes for Querybuilder2 ofc.